# Box- Not able to using box api get an "application restricted"

Tags: box-api, box

I’m trying to run the following code lines

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.box.net%2Fapi%2F1.0%2Frest%3Faction%3Dget_ticket%26api_key%3D" + "7sx1de6h54xwbnrk2u1b6xi2edlrt5ia" + "'&amp;format=json&amp;diagnostics=true",

    function(response) {

        window.ticket = response.query.results.response.ticket;

        window.location.href = 'https://m.box.net/api/1.0/auth/' + ticket;

});
```

And I get the following response:
application_restricted

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

API v1 is no longer available.  You'll need to use the v2 OAuth2 endpoint to get an access token:

https://www.box.com/api/oauth2

See the documentation at https://developers.box.com/docs/#oauth-2